# Can I use google to determine vhosts on same IP?

Tags: google-api, virtual-hosts, google-ajax-api

Can I use google -- specifically i am thinking of the google ajax api -- to enumerate a list of host names of websites that are hosted on a particular IP address.

**Note**
Yes, I know that other mechanisms, such as MSN search and obviously DNS services can be used, but I am specificially looking for whether a google solution exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK Google doesn't give out the IP addresses in its search results (unless the URL is only accessible from IP address rather than a host name).

I know you only want Google solutions, but have you tried [My IP Neighbors](http://www.myipneighbors.com/)? You put in a URL or IP and it gives you the sites also hosted on the IP.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure you can do with google ajax api; however I think that the best solution would be more oriented towards a sysadmin job (thus ask serverfault..), mainly:

- find which nameserver is authoritative for such website
- find out which other domains using that nameserver as authoritative

simply because websites hosted on the same server are often served by the same DNS. 
On a side note, since a DNS can be authoritative for other domains (not hosted on that IP), you might want to double-check that list and do a lookup on all domains, filtering out those that are hosted on a different server.

This leaves open the question of load balancing, tho: what if a domain is hosted on more than one server?

The answer is left as an exercise to the reader. :)

Answer (score 1):

I searched through Google's forums for SEO Q&A and technical Q&A.  The issue of whether Google captures IP addresses is not directly addressed.  However, there is at least [one answer](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Webmasters/thread?tid=0e99f6c9e5a7e4ec&hl=en) which suggests Google doesn't care about IP addresses (see squibble's second response.)